# Raster Calculator in Model Designer doesn't take my input number into account

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to make this model work :
[image]

The formula in the Raster Calculator is like this : `('A'* @weightcesium )+('B' * @weightess1 ) + ( 'C' *  @weightess2 )+ ( 'D' * @weightess3 )`

However, the Raster Calculator doesn't seem to take into account the number I am giving to it... The result is just the sum of the 4 layers.

Is there someone who can guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you have defined the individual weights as a number parameter in your model? If so, then make sure that the expression dialog for the *calculation in gdalnumeric syntax* looks like the following (example of my own):

[image]